# Is there a limit on the dollar amount of a personal check?

Tags: united-states, banking, check, regulation, personal-check

Is there a limit on the dollar amount of a personal check?

Answer (score 30):

Because of the way checks are processed, you can't write a check for $100 million or more:

https://web.archive.org/web/20150629144447/http://www.bankingquestions.com/checksyoureceived/q_limitfunds.html

The field used for 'amount' has 10 digits, so anything at/above 10^10 cents (which would require 11 digits) can't be processed, at least not by normal means.

Comment: So I guess I need to write two different checks for my island.

Comment: Physically huge checks, like from Ed McMahon or the lottery, are processed on special equipment that can handle trillion dollar-plus amounts: http://assets.nydailynews.com/img/2009/06/07/alg_cowboy_lotto.jpg

Comment: I think the key here however is "automated processing"  However, there is no reason that a check has to be automatically processed.  I can't imagine a situation in which a check for only $90 million isn't going to cause the depositing bank to directly call the issuing bank anyway.

Comment: It is possible to write a personal check for more than $100 million and have it accepted, for example Harold Hamm's $974 million and change divorce settlement check: https://money.cnn.com/2015/01/09/luxury/billionaire-divorce-check-cashed/index.html

Answer (score 7):

Like the old American Express commercial: "no preset spending limit".

It is really up to the bank(s) in question how big a cheque they are willing to honour.

A larger amount would likely be *held* longer by a receiving institution to ensure that it cleared properly, but nothing written in law (in Canada, that I am aware of).

Answer (score 6):

As long as someone is willing to take it, you can write it!  I personally wrote a check for a new car.   The dealership didn't bat an eye.

Answer (score 5):

Not really. A bank will honor a million dollar check if there are funds there to let it clear.

Answer (score 5):

Many businesses will request that you get a bank-issued check for large amounts of money. The exception is often in cases where you're not going anywhere: you can write a 50,000 check for a deposit on a new house, and you'll never have a problem, but a car dealer will probably request a counter check for the same sum.

Comment: When I bought a house the escrow agent would not take a personal check and for the earnest money deposit.

Comment: I've bought cars with personal checks. But I think the dealer also ran my credit, so a) they knew I probably wasn't a scammer and b) they had a ss# to create a loan against if the check did bounce (I believe there was something in the paperwork that allowed such a loan to be created in such a circumstance).